# read first column value from a rowspan

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a table as shown below.  Upon click on the edit I want to have the value of the first TD, i.e date, how can I do that, even with the second row?

```
    <table id="foo" border="1px">
<tr> 
                    <td rowspan='3' id="date"> 
                     Monday5                   </td> 
                    <td id="Name"> 
                     Jim 
                    <a href="#" class="edit"> 
                      edit 
                     </a> 

                    </td> 
  </tr> 

   <tr> 
                    <td id="Name"> 
                      Remy 
                    <a href="#" class="edit"> 
                      edit</a> 
                    </td> 
  </tr> 


</table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you should fix your html code, as the `id` attribute is unique. I suggest you use the class attribute:

```
<table id="foo" border="1">
    <tr> 
        <td rowspan="3" class="date">Monday</td> 
        <td>Cell A1 <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td>Cell A2 <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td>Cell A3 <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td rowspan="3" class="date">Tuesday</td> 
        <td>Cell B1 <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td>Cell B2 <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td>Cell B3 <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a></td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

in the javascript code, I first check if there's a date in the current row, if not, get the first prev. row containing a date:

```
$("#foo a.edit").click(function(e){

    var tr = $(this).closest("tr"),
        date = tr.find("td.date");
    if (date.length == 0) {
        date = tr.prevAll(":has(td.date):first").find("td.date");
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    alert(date.html());
});
```

see a working demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/roberkules/WwZPY/

sidenote: i noticed that you used uppercase and lowercase names for classes. I suggest to be more consistent and name them always upper or lowercase. and css classes are case sensitive, so in order to eliminate another error source, be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, here how you can do it

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    var tr = $(this).parents('tr').eq(0);
    while (tr && !tr.find('td:first[rowspan]').length > 0) {
        tr = tr.prev();
    }
    alert(tr.find('td:first').text());
})
```

And an example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yUpTV/1/

Comment: Your haven't been specific when defining problem, so no need to downvote... anyway, here is solution http://jsfiddle.net/yUpTV/1/

Comment: it still does not solve the problem as when I click on edit on the line remy, it does not display the date, but rather displays Remy!

Comment: Have you tried the example on js fiddle? Every edit link (out of 6 I put in example) will alert corresponding "Monday" msg...

Comment: yes, the code isn`t working as expected as when I click on edit on line containing 3, it gives 3 as the alert value and not monday or tuesday..., it gives the riht value only when you click on jim

Comment: i have tried it in chrome, firefox and IE, and I always get right result. Try cleaning cache... here is the result I get (I only modified html and alert msg to get better msg): http://img.ba/vwuc

Comment: @learning let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2127/discussion-between-dugokontov-and-user281180)

Comment: I have done a test, it is clear the code is working on chrome, IE 9 but not IE 8.0, please see the image attached, in the edited part above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the -1 :) This one works as it should.

```
$(".edit").click(function(e){

    var parent_tr = $(this).parents("tr:first");
    var child_rowspan = parent_tr.find("td[rowspan]");


    if (child_rowspan.length == 0) {
        name = parent_tr.prevAll("tr:has(td[rowspan]):first").find("td[rowspan]").text();

    } else {
        name = child_rowspan.text()
    }

    alert(name);
});
```

Comment: so you copied my code and changed it only from using a class to `[rowspan]`. prefer my version, as it is more flexible. e.g. you can't add a 2nd cell using rowspan because then you can't distinguish which one contains the value.

Comment: of course i wont argue i did not look your code. tested yours locally, did not work, so tweaked it... and also , learing wants rowspan taken over.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$(this).parents("tr").children("td:first").text()
```

Answer (score -1):

Since the element is already identified, you can access it like so

```
$("#date").text();
```